# MouseEnter(), MouseExit() and MouseUp() only being triggered once in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to create an intractable crate inside of my `Unity` project.

The problem is `Unity` is only detecting these `variables` once whereas the player should be able to `hover` on and off the crate as they wish.

The code outputs these values in the `DebugLog` however they only work the first time they're performed.

Thanks in advance

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Detection : MonoBehaviour {


     void OnMouseOver()
    {
        Debug.Log("Enter");
    }

     void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exit");
    }

     void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed");
    }

}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and these functions are triggered correctly. What did you attach this script to?

Comment: Are there any other scipts interacting with the crate? maybe the collider/objects gets removed from somewhere else.

Also for a sanity check: Do you have "Collapse" on in your console? This will flatten down all logs that are the same and display a number on the right hand side of how many times it has been called.

Comment: Damn i feel stupid, yeah it was the collapse thing :P think its time for a break :D